# Wrong results on JOIN with three tables MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: Publisher, Imprint and Magazine.
A Magazine belongs to an Imprint, and only one Imprint.
An Imprint belongs to a Publisher and only one Publisher.
A Publisher has many Imprints.

I'm trying to query all Imprints, fetching data from its publisher and counting all its magazines.

My current attempt is:

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, p.name as publisher, count(m.id) as magazines
FROM imprint AS i
    JOIN publisher as p ON p.id = i.publisher 
    LEFT INNER JOIN magazine as m  ON m.imprint = i.id
ORDER BY publisher ASC, i.name ASC
```

But I'm only getting one row as a result, not all the imprints with its Publisher name and magazine count.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: `JOIN publisher as p ON e.id = i.editorial` You really should be associating the foreign key in `p` to something in here

Comment: "Where am I wrong?" - Here: `count(m.id)` - Probably missing a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `LEFT INNER JOIN` -- Is that even possible?

Comment: Come to that **what is `e` an alias for** ??

Comment: This is NOT your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting a single row is `count(m.id)`. `count` is a group function and if you don't specify any conditions to group, it will aggregate and count number of given expression values(in this case `m.id`) from all retrieved rows. So you should add `GROUP BY` phrase and specify what should be the condition to group. In this case `imprintAS`, more specifically the primary(or unique) key of `imprintAS` should be the condition.

Let me assume you have below tables:

1. publisher

```
MySQL [tmp]> SELECT * FROM publisher;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | p1   |
|  2 | p2   |
+----+------+
```

2. imprintAS

```
MySQL [tmp]> SELECT * FROM imprintAS;
+----+--------------+------+
| id | publisher_id | name |
+----+--------------+------+
|  1 |            1 | i1   |
|  2 |            1 | i2   |
|  3 |            2 | i3   |
|  4 |            2 | i4   |
+----+--------------+------+
```

3. magazine

```
MySQL [tmp]> SELECT * FROM magazine;
+----+------------+------+
| id | imprint_id | name |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 |          1 | m1   |
|  2 |          1 | m2   |
|  3 |          2 | m3   |
|  4 |          2 | m4   |
|  5 |          3 | m5   |
|  6 |          3 | m6   |
|  7 |          4 | m7   |
|  8 |          4 | m8   |
+----+------------+------+
```

Then the query should be

```
MySQL [tmp]> SELECT imprintAS.id, imprintAS.name, publisher.name as publisher, count(magazine.id) as magazines
    -> FROM imprintAS
    -> JOIN publisher on publisher.id = imprintAS.publisher_id
    -> JOIN magazine ON magazine.imprint_id = imprintAS.id
    -> GROUP BY imprintAS.id
    -> ORDER BY publisher.id ASC, imprintAS.name ASC;
```

and you will get the result below

```
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
| id | name | publisher | magazines |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | i1   | p1        |         2 |
|  2 | i2   | p1        |         2 |
|  3 | i3   | p2        |         2 |
|  4 | i4   | p2        |         2 |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Very nice answer. You should also group by publishers. If two imprints have the same publisher, your current query fails to return the right results.

Comment: Actually this does work as intended. The only thing that fails is that it only retrieves the imprints that have magazines under it and not the ones with zero magazines.

Comment: @Ikzer you're right, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for joining magazine would solve that.